# Selecting Elements from Lists

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

**A Mersenne prime is a prime number of the form $2^n−1$. Produce a list
of those n, which are at most 1,000, for which $2^n − 1$ is prime**

I am able to find the list of prime numbers:

```
Select[Table[m = 2^n - 1, {n, Range[1000]}], PrimeQ]

{3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287, 2147483647...etc.
```

How can I make a list of their corresponding "*n*" values?

Comment: make the table just `n` and the select critera `PrimeQ[2^# - 1]&`

Comment: Or use `With[{list = Range[1000]}, Pick[list, PrimeQ[2^list - 1]]]`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to remove this from "unanswered". All credit goes to the original commenters.

> @george2079

```
Select[Table[n, {n, Range[1000]}], PrimeQ[2^# - 1] &]
```

> @Henrik Schumacher

```
With[{list = Range[1000]}, Pick[list, PrimeQ[2^list - 1]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`MersennePrimeExponentQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MersennePrimeExponentQ.html) with `Select` or `Pick`:

```
Select[MersennePrimeExponentQ] @ Range[1000]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607}

```
Pick[#, MersennePrimeExponentQ /@ #]& @ Range[1000]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607}

Alternatively, you can use [`MersennePrimeExponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MersennePrimeExponent.html) with `While`:

```
i = 1; lst = {};
While[(a = MersennePrimeExponent[i++]) < 1000, AppendTo[lst, a]];
lst
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607}

Also

```
i = 1; While[MersennePrimeExponent[++i] < 1000]; 
MersennePrimeExponent[Range[i - 1]]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607}